# Error on boot, driver ebridge is already registered, cannot enter ubuntu

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

I run Ubuntu 15.10.
After clean reinstalling drivers for graphics card I got the following error while trying to boot:

```
Error: Driver 'ebridge' is already registered, aborting...
```

...after a few seconds (sometimes error above is displayed more than once), than it continues to:

> >
>   [screenshot](https://goo.gl/photos/FkPehTSqnnwpShDF7)

I have already tried to:

- Run ubuntu from USB stick, add ebridge to blacklist file (no help)
- Run in safemode, try to fix packeges (no help)
- Run in safe mode, scan all system files (no help)

Could you please help? Hope my ubuntu is not done :(

Comment: Hi,I ended up reinstaling ubuntu, now Im working on gnome :)